# Как передать массив в другой класс java

Tags: java, классы, arraylist

Прошу прощения, еще не всё знаю, учусь...
Вопрос простой по сути, я знаю что по-жесткачу туплю. Суть вот в чем.
У меня в основном классе Data_form  происоходят основные действия, и по ним заполняется массив строк, двумерный массив.
Необходимо во втором классе GetData, использовать сформировавшийся массив в первом классе (Data_form).

```
package Massiv;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Data_form {
    
    private GetData getData;
    private Data_form_Starter data_form_Starter;
    
    public String[][] twoDimArray;
    public static int long_of_lict; 
    
    public static int getLong_of_lict() {
        return long_of_lict;
    }   
    public static void setLong_of_lict(int long_of_lict) {
        Data_form.long_of_lict = long_of_lict;
    }   
    public String [][] getTwoDimArray() {
        return twoDimArray;     
    }   
    public void setTwoDimArray(String[][] twoDimArray) {
        twoDimArray = twoDimArray;
    }
    public Data_form() {
        long_of_lict=3;
        System.out.println(" Data_form start ");
        
        String [][] twoDimArray = new String [3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {
            twoDimArray [i][0] = "first";
            twoDimArray [i][1] = "second";
            twoDimArray [i][2] = "third";           
        }
        this.twoDimArray = twoDimArray.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {  //идём по строкам
        System.out.print("Data_form " + i + " "); //вывод порядкового номера элемента                           
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {//идём по столбцам
            System.out.print(" " + twoDimArray[i][j] + " "); //вывод элемента
        }
        System.out.println();//перенос строки ради визуального сохранения табличной формы        
    }
        System.out.println(" Data_form end " + twoDimArray.length);     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Data_form();
            new Data_form_Starter();
            GetData getData = new GetData(this);
        }       
        });     
    }

}
```

второй класс, в который надо передать массив, и напривер вывести в консоль

```
package Massiv;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.xml.crypto.Data;
public class GetData{
    private Data_form data_form;
    Data_form d_form;
    public GetData(Runnable runnable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println(" GetData Start runnable ");
        String[][] NewArray = d_form.getTwoDimArray();
        int longOfArray = d_form.getLong_of_lict();
        System.out.println(" GetData Start runnable longOfArray " + longOfArray);
        NewArray = data_form.getTwoDimArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  //идём по строкам
    System.out.print(" __ " + i + " __ "); //вывод порядкового номера элемента  
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {//идём по столбцам
        System.out.print(" __ " + NewArray[i][j] + " __ "); //вывод элемента        
    }   
    System.out.println();//перенос строки ради визуального сохранения табличной формы
}
}
}
```

прошу прощение за кривой код, только начинаю учится.

Comment: Ваши классы изолированны друг от друга.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю так заработает

```
package Massiv;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


    public class Data_form {
        
        private GetData getData;
        private Data_form_Starter data_form_Starter;
        
        public String[][] twoDimArray;
        public static int long_of_lict; 
        
        public static int getLong_of_lict() {
            return long_of_lict;
        }   
        public static void setLong_of_lict(int long_of_lict) {
            Data_form.long_of_lict = long_of_lict;
        }   
        public String [][] getTwoDimArray() {
            return twoDimArray;     
        }   
        public void setTwoDimArray(String[][] twoDimArray) {
            twoDimArray = twoDimArray;
        }
        public Data_form() {
            long_of_lict=3;
            System.out.println(" Data_form start ");
            
            String [][] twoDimArray = new String [3][3];
            for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {
                twoDimArray [i][0] = "first";
                twoDimArray [i][1] = "second";
                twoDimArray [i][2] = "third";           
            }
            this.twoDimArray = twoDimArray.clone();
            for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++) {  //идём по строкам
            System.out.print("Data_form " + i + " "); //вывод порядкового номера элемента                           
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {//идём по столбцам
                System.out.print(" " + twoDimArray[i][j] + " "); //вывод элемента
            }
            System.out.println();//перенос строки ради визуального сохранения табличной формы        
        }
            System.out.println(" Data_form end " + twoDimArray.length);     
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Data_form myform = new Data_form();
                Data_form myStarter = new Data_form(); // не понятный код
                GetData getData = new GetData(myform, myStarter);
            }       
            });     
        }
    
    }
```

---

```
    package Massiv;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import javax.xml.crypto.Data;
    public class GetData{
        private Data_form data_form;
        Data_form d_form;
        public GetData(Data_form data_form, Data_form d_form) {
            this.data_form = data_form;
            this.d_form = d_form;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            System.out.println(" GetData Start runnable ");
            String[][] NewArray = d_form.getTwoDimArray();
            int longOfArray = d_form.getLong_of_lict();
            System.out.println(" GetData Start runnable longOfArray " + longOfArray);
            NewArray = data_form.getTwoDimArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  //идём по строкам
        System.out.print(" __ " + i + " __ "); //вывод порядкового номера элемента  
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {//идём по столбцам
            System.out.print(" __ " + NewArray[i][j] + " __ "); //вывод элемента        
        }   
        System.out.println();//перенос строки ради визуального сохранения табличной формы
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Data_form start 
Data_form 0  first  second  third 
Data_form 1  first  second  third 
Data_form 2  first  second  third 
 Data_form end 3
 Data_form_Starter  _Start_ from Data_form_Starter 
 GetData Start runnable 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Massiv.GetData.<init>(GetData.java:13)
 at Massiv.Data_form$1.run(Data_form.java:52)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)

Выдаёт такую вот ошибку

Comment: Чуток поправил код

Comment: Починил )))
благодарю заработало)))
Благодарю
можно подсказать, что делал не так в первый раз? что почитать поподробнее на будущее про это.